# Selenium webdriver to select date

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am newbie to Selenium and not able to select date website http://www.redbus.in.
Can some one help me out? I tried to pass value to the read only text box, but it was in vain.

```
public static void setup() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Browser Set up start.. ");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.redbus.in/");
    System.out.println("Browser Set up Completed ");
}

@Test
public static void SelectSrcDest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Constructing Url to open");

    driver.findElement(By.id("txtSource")).sendKeys("Bangalore");
    driver.findElement(By.id("txtDestination")).sendKeys("Chennai");


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/img")).click();

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtOnwardCalendar').setAttribute('value','27-Mar-2014')");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/section/div[4]/button")).click();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setup();
    SelectSrcDest();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to figure out the element through ID.. Its very easy to target exactly by the ID.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("txtOnwardCalendar")).click();
WebElement selectElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("monthTable first")));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByValue("2012");
Thread.sleep(6000);
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("monthTitle"));
List<WebElement> columns011=dateWidget011.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for (WebElement cell: columns011){
//Select  Month
if (cell.getText().equals("Feb")){
cell.findElement(By.linkText("Feb")).click();
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Amir,thanks for your suggestion, I encountered with an exception:  Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results or use CSS selectors.  Please suggest me on what should i correct in my code.

Comment: This is exactly as expected. If your class name includes a space, WebDriver will see it as a "compound selector". You can either remove the space in your By.className() locator, which should still find the elements you're looking for; or you can move to finding by CSS selectors, using something like By.cssSelector(".id"), which offer far more flexibility for similar functionality. This is exactly what the exception message says.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xPath to find the element by text and then use the div id & table class to choose which trip & month to pick.

For instance in order to select the date of journey:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.redbus.in");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtOnwardCalendar")).click();

By locator = By.xpath("//div[@id='rbcal_txtOnwardCalendar']" +
                      "/table[@class='monthTable first']" +
                      "//td[contains(text(), '10')]");
driver.findElement(locator).click();
```

would select the 10th day of the first month. If you use `monthTable last` as the class instead, you get 10th day of the second month. And if you change the div id into `rbcal_txtReturnCalendar`, you can pick a date for the return trip.

Comment: This may not be true.  If they are simply located off-page, then this may be true, but if they have visibility set to none or opacity to 0%, it will NOT be clickable that way.

Comment: Well, I tested it on Selenium IDE and it worked like a charm, thus I'd argue it would also work with WebDriver. Would you say WebDriver behaves differently?

Comment: Yes.  WebDriver won't allow you select hidden elements, because it doesn't perform its commands via javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected. Should've known this, but ... guess I was being lazy.

Comment: I edited my answer after @MrTi commented on it, to contain a working sample that I tested vs. the page and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Looks good!  @user3375250 I would strongly, strongly recommend figuring out what the code does.  I don't give out code because it is much to easy to copy/paste it, and not learn anything.  Please learn how the above code works, and you will be able to write better, faster, and more flexible code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following piece of code. It works perfect

```
driver.findElement(By.id("DDLSource")).sendKeys("C");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dl[@id = 'lis']//dt[text()='Chennai']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("DDLDestination")).sendKeys("t");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dl[@id = 'dis']//dt[text()='Theni']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("calenImg")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Feb']/../..//a[text()='17']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("calendar1")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Feb']/../..//a[text()='20']")).click();
```

Comment: This is the code I have used previously for Redbus site.But just now I observed, all the elements has been changed.U can refer mine and write the script on your own

Comment: Thanks but , post changing the elements , still i couln't pick up a specific date using webdriver.

Comment: Thank you Shyamala it works ...!!!!!    driver.findElement(By.id("txtOnwardCalendar")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rbcal_txtOnwardCalendar']/table/tbody/tr[8]/td")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this to select the date:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("give id")).click();
WebElement selectElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByValue("2012");
Thread.sleep(6000);
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-monthpicker-div"));
List<WebElement> columns011=dateWidget011.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
for (WebElement cell: columns011){
//Select  Month
if (cell.getText().equals("Feb")){
cell.findElement(By.linkText("Feb")).click();
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results or use CSS selectors.

Comment: thanks for your code, @Amir,The above message was displayed after executing the code which you gave, Please advise.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("txtOnwardCalendar")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rbcal_txtOnwardCalendar']/table/tbody/tr[8]/td")).click();