# How to Handle Date field in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I need to select a date say like Year as 1947, Month as Aug and Date like 15.

What are the methods and classes that I need to use? I tried using `WebElement by xpath`. I cant locate the year and month only date is located. Please suggest me the rigt way

[image]

This is HTML Page source for that particular element

```
<td>
<div>
<div class="dais_gwt_input_div" style="margin-left: 140px; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 175px; height: 24px;">
<input id="EMPLOYEE_New_DOB" class="dais_gwt_input_Field" type="text" style="border-style: none; padding: 2px 20px 2px 6px;" maxlength="10"/>
<div id="dais_gwt_fieldcontainer_left_right_top_bottom_label" class="default-label" style="margin-top: 3px; float: left; width: 100px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; margin-left: -275px;">DOB</div>
<div id="undefined" class="dais_gwt_image_div" align="center" style="float: right; margin-top: -23px;">
<img id="undefined" class="applyclicks" align="middle" src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

All I need to know is how to locate and access the year and month I tried using arrow keys in it by using xpath and Action class  but I cannot click every time and move forward and backward, same with the month. I dont have any idea about how to handle this. I have never faced this before.

Comment: Could you please provide some html code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium webdriver to select date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149626/selenium-webdriver-to-select-date)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)